# How to display value from db into a text input as it's value?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, mysqli

below I have an iframe which deals with a file input:

```
var $fileVideo = $("<form action='videoupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_video' onsubmit='return videoClickHandler(this);' class='videouploadform' >" + 
"Video File: <input name='fileVideo' type='file' class='fileVideo' /></label>" +  
"<input type='submit' name='submitVideoBtn' class='sbtnvideo' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
 "<p class='listVideo' align='left'></p>" +
"<iframe class='upload_target_video' name='upload_target_video' src='/' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Now I have a function below where when the file has stopped uploading and has successfully uploaded into the server, it will display the name of the file uploaded:

```
    function stopVideoUpload(success, videofilename){

      var result = '';
      videocounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="videomsg'+videocounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';
          $('.listVideo').eq(window.lastUploadVideoIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(videofilename) + 
          '<input type="text" name="videoidhide" value=""/><br/><hr/></div>');
      }


      return true;   
}
```

You will also see that there is a text input next to the file name. This is relevant to my question.

Below is the php script the frame links to `videoupload.php` and this script will upload the files and insert the data into the database:

```
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileVideo"]["tmp_name"],
      "VideoFiles/" . $_FILES["fileVideo"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

    $videosql = "INSERT INTO Video (VideoFile) 
    VALUES (?)";

        if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($videosql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

            //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$vid);

//Assign the variable
$vid = 'VideoFiles/'.$_FILES['fileVideo']['name'];

 $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();     

?>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.top.stopVideoUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileVideo']['name'] ?>');
 </script>
```

Below is an example database showing the insert of the file:

Video_Question Table:

```
 VideoId (PK auto)  VideoFile
 1                  VideoFiles/carrace.mp4
 2                  VideoFiles/cricket.mov
```

Now what my question is that where you see in the mysqli code where it inserts the uploded video file into the `VideoFile` field in the db, how can I retrieve the value from the `VideoId` field and display it in the text input for each associated uploaded file?

For example if carrace.mp4 was uploaded, then retrieve the `VideoId` 1 from the db and display it in the text input next to the name of the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `$mysqli->insert_id` and append it to the file name before you call the `function stopVideoUpload`

Also `$vid` needs to be assigned before you bind it, not after

```
     $insert->execute();
     $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();     

?>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.top.stopVideoUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>, '<?php echo $id. $_FILES['fileVideo']['name'] ?>');
 </script>
```

Comment: Can I ask how you would append it to the text input value because my attempt isn't working. Keep getting error that mysqli should not be called here.

Comment: @user1930247 something like the example above.

Comment: Oh I see what you have done, it works in terms of outputting the id, but I don't want the user to be able to see the video id, hence why I want the value in a hidden input

Comment: OH, wait a minute Im not thinking, why dom't  I just put  the hidden input in the above code in your answer.

Comment: Best answer thanks, just change the line to a hidden input so future user who wants to include a hidden input from an iframe knows how its done :)